# Laid off with no NDA signed

Tags: layoff, non-disclosure-agreement

If an employee or a contractor gets laid off, but has no NDA signed.. Could they go ahead work for competitors and even take the work they have done and resell/redo for the competitors?

Comment: If there is no contract , employment agreement or NDA, than local labor laws apply.

Comment: Even with Non-Competes, in some countries they are only enforcable if the employee quit or got fired for cause, not if they get laid off through no fault of their own. Do you maybe want to add a country tag to get more focussed answers?

Comment: US company contractor

Answer (score 7):

> Could they go ahead work for competitors

That would depend on a non-compete clause. The NDA limits information, a non-compete clause limits where you can work.  The location will determine how strict the non-compete clause can be.

> and even take the work they have done and resell/redo for the
> competitors?

It depends on the work. If they own the stuff you don't have a right to use it regardless of the terms of the NDA. The NDA limits what you can disclose. But if the plan is to copy the code from the server before you leave, that could be theft.

Note: there can also be a non-compete clause between a company and a customer to prevent poaching of employees. That could limit your ability to join a company even if you didn't sign the agreement.

The exact terms can depend on national/local laws.

Comment: but if that's code i have written, can't i rewrite that code?

Comment: Yes. you can use your years of experience to start from a blank file and write new code. It get complicated when they own the key algorithm.  Lawyers may have to get involved.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: You can't own "pure" algorithms under copyright. Whether or not they can be owned under patent is a much more jurisdiction-dependent question (and, at least in the US, the law is very unclear IMHO). But at least patents have to be filed publicly, and you could advise your new employer of the possibility of infringement.

Comment: @Kevin - “You can't own "pure" algorithms under copyright. “ - You can copyright your own code though, Google learned that the hard way, when they were sued by Sun and lost a copyright court case surrounding their supposedly clean room implementation of the Java VM that Android uses. They lost the case due to a single function that had the same name that did the same function. The function was trivial code with limited ways to implement that functionality. There is also the whole “IBM compatible” situation from the 80s

Comment: @Donald: I'm not sure which case you're talking about. Sun never sued Google to my knowledge, and Oracle [lost](https://www.oyez.org/cases/2020/18-956).

Comment: [Here](https://www.theverge.com/2020/10/6/21504715/google-v-oracle-supreme-court-hearings-android-java) is an article about the case.

Answer (score 5):

> If an employee or a contractor gets laid off, but has no NDA signed..
> Could they go ahead work for competitors and even take the work they
> have done and resell/redo for the competitors?

An NDA is a Non-Disclosure Agreement and has nothing to do with a non-compete agreement. Read your contracts/documents to see what is prohibited.

If there is no signed non-compete agreement, you can work for a competitor, depending on local labor laws.

On the other hand, taking work done for one company and giving/selling it to another is theft. Don't do that.

Comment: What if you build product A for company A, don't have any NDA or non-compete, then company B who is a direct competitor of A, in the same business domain, wants to build the exact same project and you simply rebuild the exact same thing the exact same way (you don't actually steal company A's code, you simply reproduce it for company B because you know how it works)?

Answer (score 3):

The normal situation is that you are free to work for anyone willing to employ you. Your old employer is not your employer anymore. They don’t pay you anymore. Why would they be able to tell you what to do?

You are also allowed to use anything you learned. Part of your remuneration is being able to learn. (For example if you were hired to maintain some old dead end software, you would want higher pay because you don’t make any career progress).

Now taking any copyrighted code or information is a big no-no. That could get you into deep trouble. Taking company information, like a list of customers, it is very very likely that this is in your employment contract. (Many things are protected by copyright, or by other laws, but a customer list would be a fact).

Comment: Depending on the industry and the local law - breaching a Non-Compete clause can land you in serious legal trouble - your previous employer (if you have a non-compete clause) can take you to court and if the Non-compete is reasonable, the court can issue you an injunction preventing you from working during that period. So your first line is dangerous advice.

Comment: The normal case is no such clause in the contract.

Comment: Depends on Industry - every job I've had for the last 15? years has had a Non-Compete clause of some form or another in it.